# Can't see a DOM node's style visibility through Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some logic in my Javascript to make a parentnode of a node in which an event was caught, disappear. To be specific, the parent node is a PDF link, and both it and its child node (bmp image) both need to be invisible if the child fails to load.  Here is what I have outlined as my event listener function:

```
window.addEventListener('error', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
    if (event.target.id == "sheetBmp"){
        console.log("sheet bmp failed to load");
        //make the pdf disappear also
        e.target.parentNode.style.visibility=false;
        console.log("pdf nodeshould disappear");
    }
}, true);
```

and here is the styling:

```
    <a id=sheetPdf target='_blank'>
        <img id="sheetBmp" onLoad="this.style.visibility='visible'" onError="this.style.visibility='hidden'">
        </img>
    </a>
```

Note that I ran it through a debugger, and after the `e.target.parentNode.style.visibility=false;` line runs the property remains the same (blank quotes) and the visibility of the node remains visible on the webpage.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting an invalid value (`false`) to the property, so the browser is discarding it.

Acceptable values for the [visibility property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) include `"visible"` and `"hidden"`.

Comment: Thanks, this was much more simple than I expected

Comment: This is correct. In addition, the OP probably doesn't actually want `visibility` at all, since that would leave elements in the layout, but not visible. The OP probably wants `display: none`.

Comment: @rockerest Thank you also very much for citing this property, I prefer this way because now the element doesn't leave a blank white space behind after the error is thrown. Thank you for the great suggestions!